# c - error: request for member xxxxxx in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member

This is in a program meant to work with ppm image files.

I'm getting a compilation error when trying to use a function that accepts a global struct variable and extracting that image's members.

This is the global struct (declared in ppmIO.c and ppmIO.h):

ppmIO.c:

```
struct Image *instance;
```

ppmIO.h:

```
struct Image
{
  int width;
  int height;
  unsigned char *data;
};

extern struct Image *instance;
```

This is how I call my function from main:

```
  ImageInvert(&instance);
```

These are the relevant parts of my imageManip.c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <ppmIO.h>
#include <imageManip.h>

void ImageInvert(struct Image **toInvert) {


  int i;
  int pix = (*toInvert->width) * (*toInvert->height);

  for (i = 0; i < pix; i++)
    {
      *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data));
      *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data++));
      *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data++));
    }

}
```

This is my imageManip.h file:

```
#include <ppmIO.h>

void ImageInvert(struct Image **toInvert);

void ImageSwap(struct Image **toSwap);
```

These are the errors I get:

```
imageManip.c:31:23: error: request for member ‘width’ in something not a structure or union
   int pix = (*toInvert->width) * (*toInvert->height);
                       ^
imageManip.c:31:44: error: request for member ‘height’ in something not a structure or union
   int pix = (*toInvert->width) * (*toInvert->height);
                                            ^
imageManip.c:35:18: error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
       *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data));
                  ^
imageManip.c:35:60: error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
       *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data));
                                                            ^
imageManip.c:35:67: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
       *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data));
                                                                   ^
imageManip.c:35:67: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
imageManip.c:36:18: error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
       *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data++));
                  ^
imageManip.c:36:60: error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
       *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data++));
                                                            ^
imageManip.c:36:69: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
       *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data++));
                                                                     ^
imageManip.c:36:69: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
imageManip.c:37:18: error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
       *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data++));
                  ^
imageManip.c:37:60: error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
       *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data++));
                                                            ^
imageManip.c:37:69: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
       *(toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - *(toInvert)->data++));
```

Not sure if I'm accessing the members correctly or if I'm making the right use of pointers...

Comment: `*toInvert->width` --> `(*toInvert)->width`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks! I did that already and it did fix most of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with how I was using brackets.

This is a working version of the imageInvert function:

```
void ImageInvert(struct Image **toInvert) {


  int i;
  int pix = (*toInvert)->width * (*toInvert)->height;

  for (i = 0; i < pix; i++)
    {
      (*toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - (unsigned char)(*toInvert)->data);
      (*toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - (unsigned char)(*toInvert)->data++);
      (*toInvert)->data = ((unsigned char)255 - (unsigned char)(*toInvert)->data++);
    }

}
```

Comment: It becomes easier to use: `struct Image *image = *toInvert;` and then you can simply use `image->data` etc throughout.  Your replacement code, though, suffers UB (undefined behaviour) because you increment `data` as well as assign to it.  In fact, you've got some major problems; you keep changing the pointer, not the data pointed at.   That may be why you need so many casts, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks! I have indeed run into a major problem with this... how can I change the data pointed at instead of just the pointer?

Comment: I think I'd write: `void ImageInvert(struct Image **toInvert) { struct Image *image = *toInvert; int n_colour_vals = (image->width * image->height) * 3; unsigned char *data = image->data; for (int i = 0; i < n_colour_vals; i++) data[i] = 255 - data[i]; }` — which is radically simpler for multiple reasons.  It is not clear that there's any reason to pass `struct Image **toInvert`; why not use just `struct Image *image` in the interface? There may be a good reason, such as it conforms to a generic function interface for manipulating images which sometimes needs `struct Image **`.

Comment: omg thanks @JonathanLeffler That worked perfectly! I didn't know that I could access data using `data[i]`... Is data treated as a one dimensional array?

Comment: Or, if you prefer using pointers to subscripts: `void ImageInvert(struct Image **toInvert)
{
    struct Image *image = *toInvert;
    unsigned char *data = image->data;
    unsigned char *end = data + (image->width * image->height) * 3;

    while (data < end)
    {
        *data = 255 - *data;
        data++;
    }
}`

Comment: Yes; you have `unsigned char *data;` as the element in the structure; that's a 1D array (vector, or just 'array') of characters.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You might want to formally answer this question: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093271/c-segmentation-fault-when-trying-to-write-a-modified-structure?noredirect=1#comment67459502_40093271)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125946/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-rockandahardplace).